# Отследить скачивание файла браузером

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно **отследить скачал пользователь файл или нет**. Если скачал, то у меня удаляться он будет с сервера. В данный момент он удаляется по таймеру, после нажатия кнопки "скачать"

> но это совсем не хорошее решение

возможно ли такое?

Comment: Но ты ведь можешь отследить статус запроса на скачивание, если никаких исключений не произошло, то скорее всего скачал, хотя да, надеяться на это не стоит, он мог и отменить скачивание или скорость соединения низкая... Не уверен что можно как-то это проверять, у js нет доступа к файловой системе ОС

Comment: Можно скачивать файл с помощью AJAX.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko ссылочкой не поделитесь?

Comment: Можете посмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  спасибо

Comment: Ещё можно отправлять юзера на другую страницу, после того как началась загрузка, а там уже дело за куками)

Comment: @theblackpost как это сделать? Как понять началась ли вы загрузка